# Lower bound of chromatic number of some graph

Tags: graph-theory

Here is the statement I'm trying to prove:

> For $n = 2^m+1$, consider the graph on the pairs of integers $(i, j)$ with $1< i < j < n$ and edges between $(i, j)$ and $(k, l)$ if $j =k$.
>   Prove that the chromatic number is at least $m$.

I tried to do it by induction by finding some vertex that is connected to all (or enough) vertices of the graph for $m-1$, but didn't succeed.
I tried to find some structure, but I really don't know what to look for.

Let me know if you have some ideas!

Thank you

Comment: Is there any restriction on the pairs $(i,j)$ besides the inequality $i\lt j$? Can $i$ and $j$ be any real numbers, or are they restricted to integers? In any case, it seems to be an infinite graph, and the chromatic number seems to be infinite.

Comment: Was $i\lt j$ a typo for $1\le i\lt j\le n$? That will make it a finite graph. But what is $M$? Is $M=m$?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question will help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579892/construction-of-a-triangle-free-graph-of-chromatic-number-1526

Comment: Yes, n and j are integers smaller n, i edited it, thanks.

Comment: That's the same construction, thank you very much !

Comment: Your statement is true (for $m\ge2$) but not sharp. I think you still have a couple of typos: $1\lt i\lt j\lt n$ should be $1\le i\lt j\le n$ and "chromatic number at least $m$" should be "chromatic number greater than $m$".