# How to Construct Graphs with High Chromatic Number but no Complete Subgraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

How does one go about constructing graphs with high chromatic number, but which don't contain any copies of $K_4$ (and thus any larger complete graphs) as subgraphs?  In particular, how do you start with a graph $G$ and glue together some copies of $G$ to get a graph with higher chromatic number?

My impression is that there are various procedures for doing this in a sort of ad hoc way, but I couldn't find a collection or discussion of the topic in particular, and I'm not active in graph theory.  Does anyone know a reference for such things, or are willing to show a few of the tricks of the trade?

Thanks!

Btw, this is a more general version of a question I asked over here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382311/ways-to-increase-chromatic-number-of-graph if you want to see a much more complicated and specific formulation.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579892/construction-of-a-triangle-free-graph-of-chromatic-number-1526

Comment: Thanks, good comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, undirected graph is perfect if for each induced subgraph $H$ of $G$, $\omega(H)=\chi(H)$. A nice generalization due to Gyárfás is called chi-boudedness.

A graph $G$ is chi-bounded if there is a function $f$ such that $\chi(H) \leq f(\omega(H))$ for each induced subgraph $H$ of $G$.

The question whether a graph is chi-bounded or not is far from trivial, since there are graphs which are triangle-free while having arbitrarily large chromatic number and hence they are obviously not chi-bounded.

There is a nice collection of procedures for generating triangle-free graphs with arbitrary large chromatic number in "A survey of $\chi$-boundedness" by Alex Scott and Paul Seymour. You can find a preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.07500).

Here is a list with references:

- Tutte's construction, nicely described in [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=ObRdAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=Construction%20of%20triangle%20free%20graphs%20with%20k%20chromatic%20number%20tutte&source=bl&ots=jPFw5YkIDY&sig=ACfU3U05H1yh8c7ehd1xOIg8GbPhkhSsaQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqytbSwa_qAhVPpYsKHbgYAxYQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=Construction%20of%20triangle%20free%20graphs%20with%20k%20chromatic%20number%20tutte&f=false) book
- [Mycielski’s construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian)
- [Kneser graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph)
- [Shift graphs](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1968-04.pdf)
- [Zykov’s construction](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=5974&option_lang=eng)
- [Ramsey graphs](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Ecyan/Teaching/Math689/ramsey5.pdf)
- [The Burling graph](https://locus.siam.org/doi/xml/10.1137/17M1157374)

There might be more...

Comment: Wow, awesome answer!  Looking forward to checking some of this stuff out.  I'm gonna bumble around with a computer and try to get that the coloring number for $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\geq 7$ after seeing some very simple techniques prove that in the plane it's $\geq 5$.  But I wanted to see if there's a more elegant way to get a $5+2 = 7$-chromatic graph by 'putting some planar sheets together' first.

Comment: Not from actual "planar graphs" ofc; I just mean graphs whose vertices are in 2-dimensional affine subspaces.