# Connection between independence number and complete induced subgraphs.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Question**:

I'm trying to prove that if the independence number of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is $n$, then $V$ may be partitioned into $n$ sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{i}S_i=V$ and for each $S_i$, the induced subgraph $G[S_i]$ is complete.

**My attempt at a constructive proof**:

Let $X$ be a maximum independent set in $G$ with $|X|=n$. For each $x_i \in X$, let $S_i$ be the set of vertices of the largest complete subgraph of $G[N(x_i) \cup \{x_i\}]$. From here, I wanted to show that for each $v \in V \setminus X$, $v$ must be in at least one such $S_i$ but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Isn't $G=C_5$ a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the complementary graph $\overline G$, the statement you are trying to prove is equivalent to the following:

> If the clique number of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is $n$, then $V$ be be partitioned into $n$ independent sets, i.e., $\chi(G)\le n$.

This, of course, is falso; the self-complementary graph $C_5$ is the simplest counterexample to this statement and to your statement. In fact, there are triangle-free graphs (clique number $2$) with arbitrarily high chromatic number; see the answers to the question [Construction of a triangle-free graph of chromatic number 1526](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579892/construction-of-a-triangle-free-graph-of-chromatic-number-1526).

Comment: $C_5$ is definitely a counter example, thanks for pointing this out! I think I over-generalized the statement. In my problem, vertices are (x, y) coordinates in the plane and two vertices have an edge between them if the line intersecting them does not have positive slope, I think cycles can only occur in connected subgraphs in this context so $C_n$ wouldn't show up for $n \geq 4$. I wonder if this added constraint makes the statement true.

Comment: Have you heard of [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem)?

Comment: Wow, this just blew my brain. Dilwerth's theorem is _exactly_ what I was originally trying to prove, thanks so much!